# try except syntax error

Tags: python, try-catch

I have a problem with the next code.

```
try: 1+1
except Exception as exception: pass
1+1
try: 2+2
except Exception as exception: pass
```

The result I get in the prompt is

```
... ...   File "<stdin>", line 3
    1+1
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> ... ... ... 4
```

However the next code executes with no error.

```
try: 1+1
except Exception as exception: pass

try: 2+2
except Exception as exception: pass
```

My `sys.version_info` is:

```
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Why do I get the syntax error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the interactive prompt, there needs to be a blank line between a block (such as a `try`/`except` block) and the next independent command. This is only in the REPL, when running a `.py` file it's not necessary.

Comment: @Usobi basically, when you're in the REPL and the prompt is `...` instead of `>>>`, you're still inside a block.